# SQLite near "(" syntax error

Tags: sqlite, syntax, syntax-error

Help please, try to create a small database, but when you click on the Save button app crashes here with this error:

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE kvartiry_table (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , Квартира text not null, Город text not null, Улица text not null, Дом integer, Кв integer, Цена за сутки integer, VARCHAR(255));

Code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.util.Log;

public class KvartDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements BaseColumns {

// константы для конструктора
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "kvart_db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "kvartiry_table";

public static final String NAME_COLUMN = "Квартира";
public static final String CITY_COLUMN = "Город";
public static final String STREET_COLUMN = "Улица";
public static final String HOME_COLUMN = "Дом";
public static final String KVARTIRA_COLUMN = "Кв";
public static final String PRICE_COLUMN = "Цена за сутки";

private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE "
+ TABLE_NAME + " (" + BaseColumns._ID
+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " + NAME_COLUMN
+ " text not null, " + CITY_COLUMN + " text not null, "
+ STREET_COLUMN + " text not null, " + HOME_COLUMN + " integer, "
+ KVARTIRA_COLUMN + " integer, " + PRICE_COLUMN + " integer, "
+ " VARCHAR(255));";

private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "
+ TABLE_NAME;

public KvartDB(Context context) {
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public KvartDB(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION, errorHandler);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Log.w("LOG_TAG", "Обновление базы данных с версии " + oldVersion
+ " до версии " + newVersion
+ ", которое удалит все старые данные");
// Удаляем предыдущую таблицу при апгрейде
db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
// Создаём новый экземпляр таблицы
onCreate(db);
}

}
```

Comment: Please post question in English. Not everyone can understand the language, you have posted the question in.

Comment: `PRICE_COLUMN + " integer, " + " VARCHAR(255));"` - Are you missing a column name before VARCHAR(255)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE kvartiry_table (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , Квартира text not null, Город text not null, Улица text not null, Дом integer, Кв integer, Цена за сутки integer, VARCHAR(255))
```

This is incorrect SQL. There's few things that are wrong:

- Make your column names latin, don't use Russian.
- "Цена за сутки" has spaces in the name, SQL columns can't have spaces in their names unless column names are quoted.
- You have a dangling `VARCHAR(255)` that has no column name in front of it.

This might work:

```
CREATE TABLE kvartiry_table (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "Квартира" text not null, "Город" text not null, "Улица" text not null, "Дом" integer, "Кв" integer, "Цена за сутки" integer, SOME_TEXT_COLUMN VARCHAR(255))
```